# Fast dictonary in C without linear search

Tags: c, data-structures, dictionary

How can I make a fast dictonary ( String => Pointer and Int => Pointer ) in C without a linear search? I need a few ( or more ) lines of code, not a library,  and it must be possible to use it in closed-source software (LGPL, ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  A hash table will have a constant-time lookup.  [Here are some excerpts in C](http://bd-things.net/hash-maps-with-linear-probing-and-separate-chaining/) and [an implementation in C (and Portuguese :)](http://wiki.portugal-a-programar.org/c:snippet:hash_table_c).

Comment: Or a binary tree, if you can't use a hash.

Comment: Hardly portuguese if the variable names and comments are in english? ;)

Comment: A hash table can potentially do O(1) reads and expected amortized O(1) writes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a **[Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)** which stores objects using a hash code. The lookup time is constant.

A **[Binary Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)** can traverse and lookup an element in *log(n)* time.

Comment: A hash function for strings is *NOT* constant time.

Comment: A binary tree for string searching is *NOT* long(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ternary Search Tree](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2001/jw-0216-ternary.html) was born for this mission.

Answer (score 1):

If you strings will be long, you cannot consider the "Hash table" as constant time! run-time depends on the length of the string! for long strings, this will cause problems. additionally, you have the problem of collisions with too small of a table or too poor of a hash function.

if you want to use hashing, please look at karp-rabin. if you want an algorithm dependent SOLELY upon the size of the word you are searching for, please look at aho-corasick.

Comment: It's constant time with respect to N (the number of strings), but may also vary with other factors (e.g. string length). The terminology "constant time" implies "with respect to the size/number of input values". Whether it's "performant enough" in this case is up for debate.